# Error 2042 for Application.VLookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to lookup a cell value in another sheet. When I use the following code, the output for `debug.print` is `Error 2042`. if I replace `Cells(i, store).Value` with a static value like "39875", it works perfectly.

```
With Sheets("250")
    numCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

numRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Dim store
Dim agType
For i = 1 To numCol
    If Trim(Cells(1, i).Value) = "Balancing Seg" Then store = i
    If Trim(Cells(1, i).Value) = "Ag Type" Then agType = i
Next

Sheets("Worksheet").Activate
For i = numRows To 1 Step -1
    With Worksheets("250")
        x = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, store).Value, .Range("A1:I" & .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count), 9, False)
    End With
    Debug.Print (x)
Next
```

Am I doing something wrong with the first argument of the VLookup?

Comment: Does `Store` definitely have a value when you run the code?

Comment: Ditto `numRows`.

Comment: Yep, store has a value. I set breakpoints and checked.

Comment: Do any cells contain an error value?

Comment: I've added the line for numRows to the above code, but yes that definitely has a value.

Comment: I take it back. numRows was pulling the number of rows from 250..not from Worksheet as I had intended.=, so it was trying to look up blank cells. It's fixed now, thank you SJR!

Comment: OK, always make sure you include sheet references.